# mergExt - Can I choose a location and a name for saving a video with mergAV?

Tags: video-capture, livecode

I all, I'm searching a way to save a recorded video to a location and a name for get it in a next session, do you know if it is possible with mergAV? I only find a way to save it the library. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try renaming the file to a location in the documents folder:

```
rename file "/var/mobile/Applications/3AA3B758-A8CA-422F-AC66-AD9887FF2DED/Documents/output.m‌​ov" to specialFolderPath("documents")&"/yourfilename.mov"
```